# How to defferentiate several running java Jar in windows

Tags: java, windows, jar, process, pid

I have a Windows server which run several java .jar running in the background. 
For example programABC.jar, programDEF.jar, and so on.
They were triggered trough the Windows task scheduler.

I can see through DOS command line `tasklist` or Windows "Task Manager" there are a couple of java.exe currently running, I can also tell their Process ID. **But I don't know which instance belong to which jar program. How to identify these processes?**

As a comparison in linux if we have the Process ID we can just `cat /proc/YOURPID/maps` that will give a clue what is the program name, run from where, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In Task Manager processes tab click View|Select Columns.  Scroll down the list then select "Command Line" then OK.  You should see the command line of the process which should include the .jar file used.

Comment: Perfect @JJF , thank you so much! That's all I need. Could you please add it as an answer? So I can mark it as a proper answer. Maybe useful for other people as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Task Manager processes tab click View|Select Columns. Scroll down the list then select "Command Line" then OK. You should see the command line of the process which should include the .jar file used.